# Integrated Terminal is missing in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I just started coding with Visual Studio Code based on 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code

But I cant find "View > Integrated Terminal"

instructions :

Open the Integrated Terminal from Visual Studio Code by selecting **"View > Integrated Terminal"** from the main menu.

[image: check this]

I need it to complete my code
how to solve it? where can i find it ?

Comment: Is it really such a leap of imagination to realise that `View > Integrated Terminal` is the same as `View > Terminal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminology has changed slightly, the menu item is no longer called `Integrated Terminal`, it is simply `Terminal` - as per [these docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

So `View > Terminal` should get you where you want to be.

Comment: @Matt In future, we shouldn't really be answering questions like this, this one was pretty obvious and OP should have been able to figure it out.

Comment: I honestly did not noticed that. mistake! :(